# How to convert an xml format to similar mongodb structure?

Tags: xml, mongodb

I have the following xml

```
<Employees>
    <employee> 
        <personal-details>
            <last-name>A</last-name>
            <first-name>Mahendran</first-name>
        </personal-details>
    </employee>
</Employees>
```

To insert the same into mongodb I used it in the following way:

```
employees = {"employee" : 
    { "personal-details" :
        { "last-name" : "A",
          "first-name" : "Mahendran",
        }
    }
}

db.employees.insert(employees)
```

Question:

Now I have a changed xml format.

```
<Employees>
    <employee id="I-1111"> 
        <personal-details>
            <last-name>A</last-name>
            <first-name>Mahendran</first-name>
        </personal-details>
    </employee>
</Employees>
```

NOTE: I have added "id" attribute to employee.
How to modify the existing mongo structure to incorporate this.

Comment: How do you want to add it? MongoDB is schemaless, so you can a field at any time. You'll just need to decide where it belongs in your structure.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#update. Accordingly you can do this.

```
db.employees.update(
    { last-name: "A" },
    { $set: { id: "I-1111" }
);
```

Note that it will only update one document unless you use **multi** true.